# Weird TypeError when using the Datetime/Time module?

Tags: python, python-3.x, debugging

So I'm new to programming and I had coded this tiny script to turn my internet on from two a.m. to eight a.m. (long story);

```
import os
import datetime as dt
from time import sleep


def  connect():
    print("Connecting...")
    os.system("netsh wlan connect Sushi")

def disconnect():
    print("Disconnecting...")
    os.system("netsh wlan disconnect")

def checkcon():
    attempt= 0
    while os.system("ping google.com") != 0:
        print("Unable to connect. Trying again.")
        connect()
        sleep(attempt)
        attempt = attempt + 1
        if attempt != 0:
            print("Attempt ", str(attempt), " ...")
    print("Connected successfully")


def timeformat (hr, min, sec) : #For setting proper datetime parameters.
    return (str(hr) + ":" + str(min) + ":" + str(sec))

FMT = '%H:%M:%S'
now = timeformat(dt.datetime.now().time().hour, dt.datetime.now().time().minute, dt.datetime.now().time().second)
twoam = '02:00:00'
eightam = '08:00:00'

def tdelta(a, b = now):
        tdel = dt.datetime.strptime(a, FMT) - dt.datetime.strptime(b, FMT)
        return tdel.seconds

twoto8 = tdelta(eightam, twoam)
nowto8 = tdelta(eightam)

def main():
        if  twoto8 >= nowto8:
                connect()
                checkcon()
                print("Your internet has been successfully connected")
                x = tdelta(nowto8)
                sleep(x)
                print("Time's up!")
                disconnect()
                exit()
        else:
                print("Not yet!")
                disconnect()
                x = tdelta(nowto8)
                sleep(str(x))
                main()

main()
```

But whenever I run it, I get this:

line 35, in tdelta
    tdel = dt.datetime.strptime(a, FMT) - dt.datetime.strptime(b, FMT)
TypeError: must be str, not int

I don't really understand why, because in the function tdelta, both parameters are strings, and...I don't know. Did I miss something? Do I have to specify something? Or is it just a typo I must have missed?

Also, I think a single glance at my code makes it glaringly obvious that I'm an absolute novice, so if you have any suggestions to improve my code too, I'll be eternally grateful.

I really appreciate any help. :)

EDIT: Here's the full stack trace (as per request):

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Lenovo\Desktop\ShutdownTimer.py", line 58, in <module>
main()
File "C:\Users\Lenovo\Desktop\ShutdownTimer.py", line 54, in main
    x = tdelta(nowto8)
File "C:\Users\Lenovo\Desktop\ShutdownTimer.py", line 35, in tdelta
    tdel = dt.datetime.strptime(a, FMT) - dt.datetime.strptime(b, FMT)
TypeError: must be str, not int
```

Comment: It means both `a` and `b` arguments in `tdelta` function must be strings.

Comment: You've only posted part of the stack trace. Look at the rest of it. It'll point you straight to the bad `tdelta` call.

Comment: @NickilMaveli But aren't they already?

Comment: @user2357112 done :)

Comment: No. You must explicitly specify the types to match the regex pattern.

Answer (score 0):

Lines 46 and 54 (`x = tdelta(nowto8)`) are calling `tdelta` with an integer argument, not a string. Change lines 46-47 from

```
x = tdelta(nowto8)
sleep(x)
```

to

```
sleep(nowto8)
```

and lines 54-55 from

```
x = tdelta(nowto8)
sleep(str(x))
```

to

```
sleep(nowto8)
```

as well.

Comment: Ohhh right thank you! The thing is, I had originally done that, but when this bug occurred, I thought this might *somehow* (?!?!?) be the reason why. But I appreciate it nonetheless :)

Comment: You should also revisit your `main` function. Calling itself recursively does not seem like a good idea...